# GRAPH API - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://outlook.office365.com:444/profile/v1.0/users

Tags: azure, graph, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to create a new user in my Azure AD. I'm using Graph Explorer to do so, I'm doing a POST request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users with the following in the body:
Returns the "Not Found - 404" error.

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

Comment: see if this is similar to your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964596/no-http-resource-was-found-that-matches-the-request-uri-https-outlook-office3

Answer (score 0):

If you request API with a user, the user must be a work or school account which always formats as `xxx@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`. The delegated permission is also required, and don't forget to grant admin consent in Azure Portal.

[image]

There is a similar issue: [No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://outlook.office365.com:444/profile/v1.0/users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964596/no-http-resource-was-found-that-matches-the-request-uri-https-outlook-office3).